# Pulling Option Button value when user form closes

Tags: vba, excel

I looked around for an answer but everything I saw had the option button on a sheet rather than a user form like what I'm trying to do.

Quick run-through: User clicks a button on the sheet to add info to a list, but needs to choose which list they want to add to. I have a user form pop up with option buttons to select which one they want to add to.

Problem is, I can't seem to get the values of the buttons when I go back to my code. I'm guessing that when I unload the user form, all variables and objects get cleaned so I was thinking to save a value into a global variable but the scope of the user form and scope of the code don't seem to talk to each other.

Any ideas on how I can pull the value of an option button from a user form into my module code?

I've tried these different variations:

```
    Not OptionButton1 Is Empty

    If UserForm1.OptionButton2 = True

    If UserForm1.OptionButton3.Value = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't unload the Userform from within its code, hence use `Me.Hide` instead of `Unload Me`

this way once in your code (that caleed the userform) you dtill have access to userform members

so your main code could look like

```
Sub main()

    With UserForm1 ' load the userform
        .Show ' show the useform

        MsgBox .OptionButton1 ' <-- you still have access to Userform1 members
        MsgBox .OptionButton2
        MsgBox .OptionButton3
    End With
    Unload UserForm1 ' unload userform1

End Sub
```

while your *exiting* userform code would look like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide ' just hide the userform, but still keep it "alive"
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow... such and elegant and easy solution. Yet I couldn't find it anywhere and didn't even think I could use With on a userform. Thank you for the fast and detailed response!

Comment: You are welcome. While as to the best practice for handling UserForm object you can find something better around here: what I showed you is improvable